# What is the term for this particular use of the ablative?

Tags: grammar-identification

I am currently doing a comprehension on the destruction of Numantia (Florus I.34). The comprehension question I am stuck on is as follows: 'State and explain the case of the word *fossa*'. The sentence it is in is:

> cum Scipio **fossa** atque lorica quattuorque castris circumdatos fames premeret, Numantini a duce oraverunt proelium, ut eos tamquam viros occideret; ubi non impetrabant, eruptionem facere constituerunt.

I assumed *fossa* is in the ablative case to agree with *lorica* and *castris*, and links with *circumdatos* to have some kind of meaning like "surrounded by a ditch...", but have no idea how to explain this. Is there a grammatical term (e.g. ablative of comparison, ablative absolute) to explain this use? If I'm completely wrong and it's not the ablative after all, or I've gotten the usage wrong, what is it then?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be classified as an [ablative of means](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/ablative-means) (Latin: *ablativus instrumentalis*), answering the question: “by what means?”

It is a frequent companion of the verb *circumdare*, and if you have a good dictionary, it should note that under the entry *circumdo*. You should find something like [this from Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=circumdo):

> Aliquem or aliquid (aliquā re), *to surround some person or thing (with something), to encompass, enclose, encircle with*

So we translate: *fossa circumdare* → surround with a ditch

---

Two remarks on the task you were given:

- The word “Scipio” [does not belong](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/florus1.html#34) in that sentence and makes it unparseable.
- That is not a comprehension question. It is the bad old grammar-translation method (“what case is this word and why?”). A comprehension question would be: *Cur Scipio ad Numantinos non possit accedere?* or something like that.

Comment: Well, that's how the education system teaches us Latin unfortunately. Thank you so much! This was very helpful.

Comment: What's the problem with a grammatical question like "what case is this word and why?” What IS a problem is to think that a grammatical analysis boils down to assigning labels to things. Unfortunately, many people confound grammar with (grammatical) taxonomy. Of course, to try to learn any language just by analyzing the grammar of written texts and then translating them to the native language is very odd. But this should not lead one to ridiculize grammar, as many proponents/fans of inductive-contextual methods do (which, in my opinion, only shows their ignorance of what grammar really is).

Comment: @Mitomino I may be reading to much into it, the question is fine in itself and certainly has a place in the best and most modern of Latin classes. Still, when it is called a "comprehension question," I wonder what is going on.

Comment: I suspect that is just a general term for all questions about a text, as opposed to translation itself.

Comment: That note about _Scipio_ helped! I thought he was the subject of _circumdatos_; only now do I see that _fames_ is the subject of the _cum_ clause. I guess Scipio is the subject of _occideret._